# Validating a command in Vorpal.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vorpal.js

When using the `Vorpal.js` code library, if I have created a command that looks like:

`command-name [strategy]`

and I have set the`[strategy]` command to accept only the values`"insert"`, `"update"`, and `"upsert"`, how do I validate my code within the Vorpal.js framework? I'm guessing I would need to use some sort of validation function to parse the index and log an error message to the console if the index entry is not found. Or I could parse the index for each of the three strings instead. This would require marginally more code but I wonder, which is the most *efficient* way? Or perhaps people could suggest an implementation that is quicker still? Any suggestions of alternative methodologies would be great.

I am using the current build found at:

[Vorpal.js code repository, Github](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vorpal doesn't have any custom validation method, so you can just manually validate it without too much trouble. Something like this would work:

```
const valids = ['insert', 'update', 'upsert'];
if (valids.indexOf(args.strategy) === -1) {
  this.log('Please enter a valid strategy');
  cb();
  return;
}
```

---

#### Update

Adding a validation method is now on the roadmap for Vorpal.

Comment: I can see that, but what about alternative validation methods?

Comment: Vorpal doesn't currently support any explicit validation method. What sort of alternatives are you looking at?

Comment: Parsing for a string in Javascript, rather than parsing for index entries. I was wondering which method is most efficient.